# Open a new link in a pop up is failing with unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to pop up window from a json line.

Example, this link works fine:

```
$json['msg'] = 'Welcome. Please, <a href="http://mylink/?chat_session='.$rows['id'].'">click here</a>!';
```

But when I tried to create a pop up for it, it says errors T string parsing, things like that.

For my pop up I tried using:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--function mbetter(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=600,width=550');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;}// --></script>
```

and for link

```
$json['msg'] = 'Welcome. Please, <a href="#" onClick="return mbetter('http://mylink/?chat_session='.$rows['id'].'')">click here</a>!';
```

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with escaping a string.

```
$json['msg'] = 'Welcome. Please, <a href="#" onClick="return mbetter('http://mylink/?chat_session='.$rows['id'].'')">click here</a>!';
```

Should be:

```
$json['msg'] = 'Welcome. Please, <a href="#" onClick="return mbetter(\'http://mylink/?chat_session='.$rows['id'].'\')">click here</a>!';
```

Notice how I have escaped the single quotes in your JavaScript with backslashes?

This is described in the [PHP manual on the Strings page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (). To
>   specify a literal backslash, double it (\). All other instances of
>   backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the
>   other escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be
>   output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.

Comment: THAT FINALLY WORKED!!! I guess I should have known that , but i know now... Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: I have a little problem now after implementing this, separated but connected because it only appeared after changing this. Whenever I press that  link now , my swf sound alert keeps playing without ever stoping. It's a chat and when a user wants to chat with me, i receive that link to accept the chat. Before, it used to replace the old window, but now, since it's in a new pop up window, the audio alert keeps singing. Thats life, you solve one problem and get another. I tried function stop, would not work. Any ideas would be very helpful. Thank you! (IE - worst, not even even see my swf)

Comment: @Ingrid sorry, but Flash/Actionscript is not my forte. Please ask another question about this new issue.

Comment: Sure, Treffynnon, thank you for letting me know and for all the help! I will open a new question!